# Roman Numbers - The Functional Way

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, f#, roman-numerals

Yet another exercise in converting values between the decimal and roman number systems.
I have tried the functional way.

Any comments are welcome - but I'm especially interested in answers focusing on the F# specific functional approach and less in if I obey each and every rule for roman numbers.

**A type definition:**

```
module RomanNumbers
open System

type RomanNumber = {
Roman: string;
Value: int;
}
```

Acts as a "pivot" object holding the values from both systems, so maybe the name is not quite adequate.

**Functionality**

```
let getValue = function 
    | 'I' -> 1
    | 'V' -> 5
    | 'X' -> 10
    | 'L' -> 50
    | 'C' -> 100
    | 'D' -> 500
    | 'M' -> 1000
    | ch -> failwith (sprintf "Invalid character: %c" ch)

let validate roman =    
    if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roman) then raise (ArgumentNullException())

    let exceptions = [
        "IIV"; "IIX"; "IL"; "IC"; "ID"; "IM";
        "XXL"; "XXC"; "XD"; "XM";
        "CCD"; "CCM";
        "IVV"; "IXX"; // Ascending order rule: "IVV" means 4 + 5 but should be VIV 5 + 4 (but that will also be caught by noDuplicates (se below))
        "XLL"; "XCC";
        "CDD"; "CMM"
    ]

    let noDuplicates = [ 'V'; 'L'; 'D' ] 

    roman 
    |> Seq.iter 
        (fun ch -> getValue ch |> ignore)

    exceptions 
    |> List.iter 
        (fun part -> 
            if (string roman).Contains(part) 
            then failwith (sprintf "Invalid Sequence: %s" part))

    noDuplicates
    |> List.iter 
        (fun part -> 
            if roman |> Seq.countBy (fun ch -> ch = part) |> Seq.last |> (fun (k, i) -> k && i > 1)
            then failwith (sprintf "%c can only appear once in %s" part roman))
    ()

let fromRoman roman = 
    validate roman

    let length = roman.Length
    let first = getValue roman.[0]

    if length = 1 then 
        { Roman = roman; Value = first }
    else
        let rec converter index prev sum =
            match index with
            | x when x = length -> sum
            | _ -> 
                let curValue = getValue roman.[index]
                match curValue with
                | x when x > prev -> converter (index + 1) curValue (sum + curValue - prev * 2)
                | _ -> converter (index + 1) curValue (sum + curValue)

        let value = converter 1 first first
        { Roman = roman; Value = value }

let fromDecimal value =
    if value <= 0 then raise (ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", sprintf "Decimal value must be > 0: %d" value))
    let postfixBy value postfix = sprintf "%s%s" value postfix

    let rec converter num result = 
        match num with
        | 0 -> result
        | _ when num >= 1000 -> converter (num - 1000) (postfixBy result "M")
        | _ when num >= 900 -> converter (num - 900) (postfixBy result "CM")
        | _ when num >= 500 -> converter (num - 500) (postfixBy result "D")
        | _ when num >= 400 -> converter (num - 400) (postfixBy result "CD")
        | _ when num >= 100 -> converter (num - 100) (postfixBy result "C")
        | _ when num >= 90 -> converter (num - 90) (postfixBy result "XC")
        | _ when num >= 50 -> converter (num - 50) (postfixBy result "L")
        | _ when num >= 40 -> converter (num - 40) (postfixBy result "XL")
        | _ when num >= 10 -> converter (num - 10) (postfixBy result "X")
        | _ when num >= 9 -> converter (num - 9) (postfixBy result "IX")
        | _ when num >= 5 -> converter (num - 5) (postfixBy result "V")
        | _ when num >= 4 -> converter (num - 4) (postfixBy result "IV")
        | _ -> converter (num - 1) (postfixBy result "I")

    let roman = converter value ""
    { Roman = roman; Value = value }

// Takes any roman number string and transform it to its normalized or minimal form
let asNormalizedRoman roman = fromDecimal (fromRoman roman).Value
```

**Operator extensions**

```
let inline romanOper r1 oper r2 = fromDecimal (oper r1.Value r2.Value)    
// Extending with operators
type RomanNumber 
with 
    static member inline (+) (r1, r2) = romanOper r1 (+) r2
    static member inline (-) (r1, r2) = romanOper r1 (-) r2
    static member inline (*) (r1, r2) = romanOper r1 (*) r2
    static member inline (/) (r1, r2) = romanOper r1 (/) r2
    static member inline (%) (r1, r2) = romanOper r1 (%) r2
```

---

**Some test cases**

```
printfn "Numbers from 1 to 3999"
for i in 1..3999 do
    let roman = fromDecimal i
    let decimal = fromRoman roman.Roman
    //if roman.Roman <> decimal.Roman || roman.Value <> decimal.Value then
    printfn "%A <-> %A" roman decimal


let path = "<your path>\p089_roman.txt"

printfn ""
printfn "From File: "
for line in File.ReadAllLines(path) do
    let value = fromRoman line
    let roman = fromDecimal value.Value
    if roman.Roman <> value.Roman || roman.Value <> value.Value then
        printfn "%A <-> %A" value roman

printfn ""
printfn "Test of Operators: "

let r1 = fromDecimal 1000
let r2 = fromDecimal 3

printfn "%A" (r1 + r2)
printfn "%A" (r1 - r2)
printfn "%A" (r1 * r2)
printfn "%A" (r1 / r2)
printfn "%A" (r1 % r2)
```

[**p089_roman.txt**](https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p089_roman.txt) contains [one thousand Roman numerals that are not necessarily in canonical form](https://projecteuler.net/problem=89).

---

As an attempt to minimize magic numbers and strings/chars and to get rid of the heavy match pattern in `fromDecimal`, one could define the following:

```
let I = 1
let V = 5
let X = 10
let L = 50
let C = 100
let D = 500
let M = 1000

type RomanValue = RV of int * string

let specialRomans = [ 
    RV(M, "M"); 
    RV(M-C, "CM"); 
    RV(D, "D"); 
    RV(D-C, "CD"); 
    RV(C, "C"); 
    RV(C-X, "XC"); 
    RV(L, "L"); 
    RV(L-X, "XL"); 
    RV(X, "X"); 
    RV(X-I, "IX"); 
    RV(V, "V"); 
    RV(V-I, "IV"); 
    RV(I, "I"); 
]

let getValue = function 
    | 'I' -> I
    | 'V' -> V
    | 'X' -> X
    | 'L' -> L
    | 'C' -> C
    | 'D' -> D
    | 'M' -> M
    | ch -> failwith (sprintf "Invalid character: %c" ch)
```

and then `fromDecimal` could be "reduced" to:

```
let fromDecimal value =
    if value <= 0 then raise (ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", sprintf "Decimal value must be > 0: %d" value))
    let postfixBy value postfix = sprintf "%s%s" value postfix

    let rec folder (res, num) rv =
        match num, rv with
        | 0, _ -> res, num
        | _, RV(v, s) -> 
            match num with
            | _ when num >= v -> folder (postfixBy res s, num - v) rv
            | _ -> (res, num)

    let roman, _ = specialRomans |> List.fold folder ("", value)
    { Roman = roman; Value = value }
```

I'm not sure, what I like best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General

I think the correct translation is [Roman numeral](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/r%C3%B6mische%20ziffern).

As far as I understood, it is not a good functional style to throw exceptions in case of unexpected input because it breaks the purity. An alternative approach is [Railway oriented programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/) which makes the code much cleaner and separates the business logic from the exception handling.

Internal stuff (like `getValue`) could be private.

### Function validate

The whole validation logic is placed in one function. Splitting the single rules in its own function allows to give each rule a name and it puts things together that belongs together (e.g. `exceptions` and `duplicates` are used by one rule only).

### Function fromRoman

It is not required to handle the case `length = 1` specially. The recursive `converter` function can be simplified by using fold (as you did in `fromDecimal` in the updated version)

### Function fromDecimal

The function `postfixBy` is actually not required because string can be concatinated with `result + "M"`.

---

Below is an alternative implementaion (based on your initial question) where I tried to consider the points above. The API has chnaged to `RomanNumeral.fromNumber (int -> Result<RomanNumeral, string>)` and `RomanNumeral.fromStr (string -> Result<RomanNumeral, string>)`. The `Result<a', b'>` type requires handle the error case (similar to an Option type). If desired, it can be unwrapped with an exception in case of an error using the (external) `unwrap` function. However, the actual error handling has been moved to the caller who has to handle possible errors befor getting the result.

```
open System

module RomanNumeral =    

    (* TYPES *)

    type RomanNumeral =
        { Text:string;
          Value:int}

    type private ParsingState = 
        { Sum:int;
          Prev:int } 

    (* GENERIC HELPER *)

    let private getDuplicates items = 
        items |> List.groupBy id
        |> List.filter( fun (_,set) -> set.Length > 1)
        |> List.map( fun (key,_) -> key )

    let private getNones selector items =
        items 
        |> List.map (fun x -> (selector x, x))
        |> List.filter (fst >> Option.isNone)
        |> List.map snd

    let private toError msg invalidItems =
        Error(sprintf "%s: %s" msg (invalidItems |> String.concat "; "))

    (* DOMAIN HELPER *)

    let private getOptionValue = function 
        | 'I' -> Some(1)
        | 'V' -> Some(5)
        | 'X' -> Some(10)
        | 'L' -> Some(50)
        | 'C' -> Some(100)
        | 'D' -> Some(500)
        | 'M' -> Some(1000)
        | _ -> None

    let private getValue x =
        match x |> getOptionValue with
        | Some(v) -> v
        | None -> failwith "Invalid character"

    let private parseStr str =        
        let folder state current =
            if current > state.Prev
            then { Sum = state.Sum + current - state.Prev * 2; Prev = current}
            else { Sum = state.Sum + current; Prev = current}        
        str 
            |> Seq.map getValue 
            |> Seq.fold folder { Sum = 0; Prev = 0; } 
            |> (fun x -> x.Sum)

    let private parseNumber num =
        let map = [ (1000, "M"); (900, "CM"); (500, "D"); (400, "CD"); (100, "C"); (90, "XC");
                    (50, "L");   (40, "XL");  (10, "X");  (9, "IX");   (5, "V");   (4, "IV");  (1, "I") ]
        let rec converter (result:string) num =             
            let element = map |> List.tryFind (fun (v, _) -> num >= v)                        
            match element with
            | Some (value, romanStr) -> (num - value) |> converter (result + romanStr)
            | None -> result             
        num |> converter ""

    (* VALIDATION *)

    let private validateSingeCharacters (roman:string) =
        let invaliChars = roman |> Seq.toList |> getNones getOptionValue |> List.map string
        match invaliChars with
        | _::_ -> invaliChars |> toError "Invalid Characters"
        | [] -> Ok(roman)

    let private validateNotNullOrEmpty roman =    
        match (roman |> String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace) with
            | true -> Error("Input null or empty")
            | false -> Ok(roman)

    let private validateExceptionalRules (roman:string) =
        // Ascending order rule: "IVV" means 4 + 5 but should be VIV 5 + 4 (but that will also be caught by noDuplicates (se below))
        let exceptions = 
            [ "IIV"; "IIX"; "IL"; "IC"; "ID"; "IM"; "XXL"; "XXC"; "XD"; "XM";
              "CCD"; "CCM"; "IVV"; "IXX"; "XLL"; "XCC"; "CDD"; "CMM" ]

        let invalidParts = exceptions |> List.filter (fun part -> roman.Contains(part))
        match invalidParts with
        | _::_ -> invalidParts |> toError "Invalid Sequences"
        | [] -> Ok(roman)

    let private validateNoDuplicates roman =
        let charsThatMustBeUnique = [ "V"; "L"; "D" ]
        let duplicates = charsThatMustBeUnique |> getDuplicates
        match duplicates with
        | _::_ -> duplicates |> toError "Following characters must be unique"
        | [] -> Ok(roman)

    let private validateStr x =
            x 
            |> validateSingeCharacters 
            |> Result.bind validateNotNullOrEmpty
            |> Result.bind validateExceptionalRules
            |> Result.bind validateExceptionalRules
            |> Result.bind validateNoDuplicates

    let private validateNumberGreaterThanZero number =
        match number > 0 with
        | true -> Ok(number)
        | false -> Error("Number must be greater than 0.")

    let private validateNumber x =
            x |> validateNumberGreaterThanZero

    (* PUBLIC API *)

    let fromStr str =
        str 
        |> validateStr
        |> Result.map (fun s -> { Text = s; Value = s |> parseStr})

    let fromNumber number =
        number
        |> validateNumber
        |> Result.map  (fun number -> { Text = number |> parseNumber; Value = number})

    let inline private romanOper oper (r1) (r2) = (oper r1.Value r2.Value)

    // Extending with operators
    type RomanNumeral with 
        static member inline (+) (r1, r2) = romanOper (+) r1 r2 
        static member inline (-) (r1, r2) = romanOper (-) r1 r2
        static member inline (*) (r1, r2) = romanOper (*) r1 r2
        static member inline (/) (r1, r2) = romanOper (/) r1 r2
        static member inline (%) (r1, r2) = romanOper (%) r1 r2    

module Test =

    let unwrap x = match x with | Ok(v) -> v | Error(msg) -> failwith(msg)

    // fromNumber / fromStr
    printfn "Numbers from 1 to 100"
    for i in 1..100 do
        let dec = i
        let roman = i |> RomanNumeral.fromNumber |> unwrap
        let romanRev = RomanNumeral.fromStr roman.Text |> unwrap
        printfn "%i: %s -> %i; %s -> %i" dec roman.Text roman.Value romanRev.Text romanRev.Value

    // operator
    let a = RomanNumeral.fromStr("X") |> unwrap
    let b = RomanNumeral.fromStr("XI") |> unwrap
    let c = b - a

    // error input
    let d = RomanNumeral.fromStr("fdsgfdgas")
    let e = RomanNumeral.fromNumber(-22)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the review. I've added an answer that builds on your comments and implementation. Your answer is very instructive. I haven't been aware of the Result type, - it seems rather useful. A little remark: your `validateNoDuplicates` doesn't seem to relate to the argument roman string?

Answer (score 1):

Building on JanDotNet's answer, I've revised my code, and the result is as below. I have both rethought the algorithms and the overall design and flow. Especially the validation of input is changed to use the `Result<'T,'TError>` type - and (I hope) conforms to the "railway" pattern.
One difference to JanDotNet's is that I return a roman numeral only if the input is valid, else I throw an exception, in contrast to returning a `Result<RomanNumeral, string> (Ok(RomaNumeral) or Error("<msg>")`. There may be pros and cons for both approaches so it is open for change. I hope the overall impression is a solution that is considerable more stringent and easy to follow and maintain.

```
module RomanNumerals
open System

let I = 1
let V = 5
let X = 10
let L = 50
let C = 100
let D = 500
let M = 1000

type RomanNumeral = {
    Text: string;
    Value: int 
}

let private createRoman text value = { Text = text; Value = value }

let private toError<'a> msg (invalidItems: 'a seq) =
    Error(sprintf "%s: %s" msg (String.Join("; ", invalidItems)))

let private handleResult = function
    | Ok(rn) -> rn
    | Error(msg) -> failwith(msg)

let private tryGetValue = function 
    | 'I' -> Some(I)
    | 'V' -> Some(V)
    | 'X' -> Some(X)
    | 'L' -> Some(L)
    | 'C' -> Some(C)
    | 'D' -> Some(D)
    | 'M' -> Some(M)
    | _ -> None

let private handleInvalids okResult msg invalids =
    match invalids |> Seq.isEmpty with
    | true -> Ok(okResult)
    | false -> toError msg invalids

let private validateNotEmpty str = 
    if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) then Error("The input string is empty")
    else Ok(str)

let private validateCharacters str = 
    str 
    |> Seq.map (fun ch -> (ch, tryGetValue ch)) 
    |> Seq.where (fun (ch, v) -> v.IsNone)
    |> Seq.map fst
    |> handleInvalids str "Invalid Characters"

let private validateDuplicates str = 
    let tests = [ 'V'; 'L'; 'D' ] 
    str
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun ch -> ch)
    |> Seq.where (fun (key, data) -> tests |> List.contains key && data |> Seq.length > 1)
    |> Seq.map fst
    |> handleInvalids str "These chars can only appear once"

let private validateInvalidSequences str = 
    [ "IIV"; "IIX"; "IL"; "IC"; "ID"; "IM";
    "XXL"; "XXC"; "XD"; "XM"; "CCD"; "CCM";
    "IVV"; "IXX"; "XLL"; "XCC"; "CDD"; "CMM" ] 
    |> List.where ((string str).Contains)
    |> handleInvalids str "Invalid sequence(s)"

let private validateString str =
    str
    |> validateNotEmpty
    |> Result.bind validateCharacters
    |> Result.bind validateDuplicates
    |> Result.bind validateInvalidSequences

let private convertString str = 
    let getValue ch = (tryGetValue ch).Value // We know by now, that it will return a valid value

    let folder (sum, prev) current = 
        if (current > prev) then (sum + current - prev * 2, current)
        else (sum + current, current)

    let value = 
        str
        |> Seq.map getValue
        |> Seq.fold folder (0, 0)
        |> fst

    createRoman str value

let private isNaturalNumber num = 
    match num with 
    | x when x > 0 -> Ok(num) 
    | _ -> Error(sprintf "%d is not a natural number > 0" num)

let private validateNumber num = isNaturalNumber num

let private convertNumber num =
    let limits = 
        [ (M, "M"); (M-C, "CM"); (D, "D"); (D-C, "CD"); 
        (C, "C"); (C-X, "XC"); (L, "L"); (L-X, "XL"); 
        (X, "X"); (X-I, "IX"); (V, "V"); (V-I, "IV"); (I, "I"); ] 
        |> List.skipWhile (fun (v, s) -> v > num)

    let rec converter lims value result =
        match value, lims with 
        | 0, _ -> result
        | _, (v, s)::_ when value >= v -> converter lims (value - v) (result + s)
        | _, _::tail -> converter tail value result

    createRoman (converter limits num "") num

let fromString str =
    str
    |> validateString
    |> Result.map (fun s -> convertString s)
    |> handleResult

let fromNumber num =
    num
    |> validateNumber
    |> Result.map (fun n -> convertNumber n)
    |> handleResult

let inline private romanOper oper (r1) (r2) = fromNumber (oper r1.Value r2.Value)
// Extending with operators
type RomanNumeral with 
    static member inline (+) (r1, r2) = romanOper (+) r1 r2 
    static member inline (-) (r1, r2) = romanOper (-) r1 r2
    static member inline (*) (r1, r2) = romanOper (*) r1 r2
    static member inline (/) (r1, r2) = romanOper (/) r1 r2
    static member inline (%) (r1, r2) = romanOper (%) r1 r2
```

**Public Helper Functions**

```
// Returns the minimal representation of an input string roman expression
let asCanonicalRoman str = fromNumber (fromString str).Value

let romanRange start stop =
    let decStart = (fromString start).Value
    let decStop = (fromString stop).Value
    let step = if decStart <= decStop then 1 else -1
    seq { for dec in decStart..step..decStop do yield fromNumber dec }

let toString roman = sprintf "%s <-> %d" (roman.Text) (roman.Value)
let printRoman roman = printfn "%s" (toString roman)
```

**Test Cases**

```
printfn "Numbers from 1 to 3999"
for i in 1..3999 do
    let roman = fromNumber i
    let decimal = fromString roman.Text
    //if roman.Roman <> decimal.Roman || roman.Value <> decimal.Value then
    printfn "%s <==> %s" (toString roman) (toString decimal)



//printfn ""
//printfn "From File: "
//let path = "<your path>.p089_roman.txt"
//for line in File.ReadAllLines(path) do
//    let value = fromString line
//    let roman = fromNumber value.Value
//    if roman.Text <> value.Text || roman.Value <> value.Value then
//        printfn "%s <==> %s" (toString value) (toString roman)

//printfn ""
//printfn "Operator testing:"
//let r1 = fromNumber 5
//let r2 = fromNumber 3
//printRoman(r1 + r2)
//printRoman(r1 - r2)
//printRoman(r1 * r2)
//printRoman(r1 / r2)
//printRoman(r1 % r2)


//romanRange "X" "C" |> Seq.iter printRoman
//romanRange "C" "X" |> Seq.iter printRoman
```